# LinkedIn oAuth not working

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, hello.js

I have Facebook and Google working, but can't get LinkedIn to work. Nothing to be logged, there is no return, anything, nothing...

I added my app on hello.js proxy server as well. But every time I am getting following error:

```
{ message: "Unknown authentication scheme" }
```

Comment: *How* did you try LinkedIn? Please show some code (without credentials, of course)

Comment: I am using hello.js library to do the same.

Comment: Did you resolve this?